# Foursquare OAuth Request from Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, console, foursquare

I've been storing the profile url for users that authenticate with Foursquare like this: foursquare_url = "http://foursquare.com/#{access_token.info.nickname}"

It seems that Foursquare stopped providing nickname in the access_token, so now I save the url like this: foursquare_url = access_token.extra.raw_info.canonicalUrl

The issue is that some users authenticated before I made the change, so they all have 'http://foursquare.com/' as a profile url. How can I loop over those users and store the correct url?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you store access_token or raw_info information in the database ?

Comment: No, I'm wishing that I did now.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it in any other way. Next time the user logs in, save the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a request on a user's behalf, you need to use their access_token. If you don't have those stored in your database, you'll have to capture it the next time they authenticate your site and fetch the needed information via the foursquare API.